# The following bind parameters (56:44.0) in the task command <MERGE QUERY> are not bound to any value

Tags: oracle, mapping, toad, oracle-data-integrator

I have developed a package in ODI which has couple of variables and followed by the mapping, these variables are used inside the Mapping transformation when I run the scenario I am getting this error :  The following bind parameters (56:44.0) in the task command  re not bound to any value. All the bind parameters should be bound for the command to be successful.

I ran the MERGE SQL (Generated by ODI) in Toad with replacing the parameter with values that was generated during the runtime, and SQL executed without error, but when running this in ODI is causing an error, Could you please help me to know how can we debug such errors? what could have caused an issue?

(sorry could not share the merge query as the query is too large)

Answer (score 0):

You sould add variable on package properties. Like this:
[image: add var odi]